# How to get innertext which is not enclosed in any html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My html is -

```
​<div>
    <span>spanText</span>
    nonspantext
</div>
​​​​​​
```

My js is -

```
​$(function(){
    alert($("div").text());
});​
```

What I want to get is "nonspantext" as alert.
Fiddle to begin is here - http://jsfiddle.net/UHr2x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's quite a good use case to use good old DOM API.

```
$('span')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue;
```

And a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/d67nR/).

Seems more efficient than James' solution.

Comment: ok. It works. I get it right. :) Thanks. One more thing I should inline all the html tags in this way - </span>nonspantext</div> to get rid of new lines.

Comment: @MotaBOS As you can see on the jsfiddle, it's not always necessary.

Comment: I have added quotes around in your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/d67nR/1/. Here I am getting new lines before and after.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get the contents (including text nodes) of an element, and then filter the result to leave only the text nodes:

```
$("div").contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3;  
}).text();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/UHr2x/3/). Notice that the result includes new lines, so you might want to trim it before using it.

Comment: That should solves my problem but as you mentioned it could come with newlines or spaces. So I am enclosing nonspantext with another span. That will make my work easier. Anyway thanks and I didn't knew abt the solution you gave.